# cannot import modules from subdirectories that are in the django app parent directory

Tags: python, django

Django doesn't seem to be able to import modules from a subdirectory.

I've got a file structure like this:

->project_folder

---->app_folder

------->subdir

when I store a script in app_folder, i can import it, so the command 'from project_folder.app_folder.module import *' works, but I get a module not found error when I do 'from project_folder.app_folder.subdir.module import *'

How do I get around this? I just want to keep my files nicely organized

Answer (score 9):

have you got an `__init__.py` in your subdir? Python needs this file to treat a directory as a package.

Answer (score 0):

put an import in the init file of your app (not subdirecotry).
I have this structure and the following import in  init.py file
app/views_dir/group_views.py
The following line is the only line of code in my init file

from views_dir.group_views import test